# October CMS - sorting records - example of the partial for the toolbar icons?

Tags: sorting, octobercms

I'm excited that the October CMS recently added back-end functionality for sorting records in the list view. But I'm having some trouble getting it to work. The documentation is [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/reorder). I've followed the direction like so:

In my controller, I implemented the `ReorderController`:

```
<?PHP namespace BTruchan\Team\Controllers;

use Backend;
use BackendMenu;
use BackendAuth;
use Backend\Classes\Controller;
use System\Classes\SettingsManager;

class Members extends \Backend\Classes\Controller 
{
    public $implement = [
        'Backend.Behaviors.FormController',
        'Backend.Behaviors.ListController',
        'Backend.Behaviors.ReorderController'
    ];

    public $formConfig = 'config_form.yaml';
    public $listConfig = 'config_list.yaml';
    public $reorderConfig = 'config_reorder.yaml';

    public $requiredPermissions = ['btruchan.team.manage'];

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        BackendMenu::setContext('BTruchan.Team', 'team');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->makeLists();
        $this->makeView('reorder');
    }
}

?>
```

I've created the reorder view file (`reorder.htm`) which contains:

```
<?= $this->reorderRender() ?>
```

My `config_reorder.yaml` file contains:

```
# ===================================
#  Reorder Behavior Config
# ===================================

# Reorder Title
title: Reorder Members

# Attribute name
nameFrom: name

# Model Class name
modelClass: BTruchan\Team\Models\Members


# Toolbar widget configuration
#toolbar:
# Partial for toolbar buttons
#    buttons: reorder_toolbar
```

You'll notice that the `reorder_toolbar` partial is commented out. That's because I really don't know what's supposed to go in that toolbar. I haven't been able to find any documentation that shows the contents for the _reorder_toolbar.htm file.

Unsurprisingly, with the code commented out, it throws an error:

> Undefined variable: reorderToolbarWidget

*Some additional information:*

It was suggested that I read up on list toolbars [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#adding-toolbar).

So I added the following toolbar partial (named `_reorder_toolbar.htm`):

```
<div data-control="toolbar">
    <a
        href="<?= Backend::url('btruchan/team/members/create') ?>"
        class="btn btn-primary oc-icon-plus">
        New Team Member
    </a>
    <button
        class="btn btn-default oc-icon-trash-o"
        disabled="disabled"
        onclick="$(this).data('request-data', {
            checked: $('.control-list').listWidget('getChecked')
        })"
        data-request="onDelete"
        data-request-confirm="Delete Team Member: Are you sure?"
        data-trigger-action="enable"
        data-trigger=".control-list input[type=checkbox]"
        data-trigger-condition="checked"
        data-request-success="$(this).prop('disabled', false)"
        data-stripe-load-indicator>
        Delete
    </button>
</div>
```

But I'm still getting an error:

> Undefined variable: reorderToolbarWidget
>   /var/www/terrasearch/public/modules/backend/Behaviors/reordercontroller/partials/_container.htm
>   line 1

The code, in October CMS, which that error message is referring is:

```
<?php if ($reorderToolbarWidget): ?>
    <!-- Reorder Toolbar -->
    <div id="<?= $this->getId('reorderToolbar') ?>" class="reorder-toolbar">
        <?= $reorderToolbarWidget->render() ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>

<!-- Reorder List -->
<?= Form::open() ?>
    <div
        id="reorderTreeList"
        class="control-treelist"
        data-control="treelist"
```

I've tried to trace this error down. It seems like, in `\public\modules\backend\behaviors\ReorderController.php`, the `reorder()` function is not being called, which means that the `prepareVars()` function is also not being called. This prevents the following code from being executed:

```
$this->vars['reorderToolbarWidget'] = $this->toolbarWidget;
```

ReorderController.php:: makeToolbarWidget() is being called and seems to be OK. I've checked $this->toolbarWidget, and it seems to contain perfectly good data. (It isn't NULL).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. What is the `toolbarWidget` used for? In the docs, it's said that the file of reorder must be called `reorder.htm`. [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/reorder#reorder-display)

Answer (score 2):

The ReorderController is a behavior, so it's meant to be called as a controller destination (e.g. `example.com/backend/btruchan/team/members/reorder`). It's not coded to be called as a view the way you have it in your `index` function.

In the ReorderController source, the `reorder` function is the only method that calls the `prepareVars` protected function which is the only place that the `reorderToolbarWidget` is defined for the page. That `prepareVars` function isn't available from the host controller.

So, rather than try to create a view with `$this->makeView('reorder');`, create a toolbar button in the `_list_toolbar.htm` partial that points to the `reorder` destination url. For example:

```
<div data-control="toolbar">
    <a href="<?= Backend::url('btruchan/team/members/create') ?>" class="btn btn-primary oc-icon-plus">New Member</a>
    <a href="<?= Backend::url('btruchan/team/members/reorder') ?>" class="btn btn-primary oc-icon-sort">Reorder Members</a>
</div>
```

When you click on the "Reorder Members" button, you'll be directed to a new page with the records that can be reordered.

You can use the `_reorder_toolbar.htm` partial to add anything you want at the top of the reorder page. Or, not use it at all.

Comment: The Builder plugin properly generated all the necessary files, but did not add the reorder button to the menu.  This helped me, thanks.